# What kind of transactions we can find in Hyperledger Fabric blocks?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In Bitcoin blockchain, transactions are only of the type "transferring some amount from X to Y", so we always have an actual change the blockchain.

In Hyperledger Fabric transaction are like:

- Instatiate some chaincode in a channel
- Invoke some chaincode (that may be just a query to show a certain
  asset in the ledger / world state)

I'm sure that instantiating chaincode in some channel or running something that changes the world state are transaction that qualify to fit in a block.
What I don't understand is exactly which transactions can enter in the next block. If some chaincode does not write or update the world state (in RW sets, the Read set is the same of the Write one) can still be included in the next block? Or can be safely "discarded"?

Answer (score 1):

All endorsing peer must have instantiated chaincode so that they can simulate transactions and create Read/Write(RW) set. Installing and instantiating chaincode are different transaction than regular invoke.

Invoking some transaction meansa it can be one of

1. Query
2. Adding Asset, Updating Asset, Deleting Asset

HF maintains versioning of each unique key and it increases chronologically when we update same asset. This versioning (MVCC - Multiversion concurrency control) avoid double-spending problem as well.

HF dont care about whatever value we puts for key(Value could be anything).

Lets assume we have to add car asset with key `car1` and value is `{"name":"Audi", "owner":"ABC"}`.
When we send the transaction to all endorsing peer, they create RW set as below

- Read Set: NA
- Write set: `Key-car1, version-1, value-{"name":"Audi", "owner":"ABC"}`

When the tx gets committed to blockchain, one of the block will have this transaction and the current state database (Couch db or level db) will heve this latest value for that key : `Key-car1, version-1, value-{ "name": "Audi", "owner": "ABC"}`

Let's assume if we updating this same asset(car1)

> car1 - { "name": "Audi", "owner": "PQR"}

Here we are changing owner from `ABC` to `PQR`

This time Endorsing peer create the following RW set

- Read Set: Key-car1, `version-1`
- Write set: Key-car1, `version-2`, value-{"name":"Audi", "owner":`"PQR"`}

Once the tx gets committed to the blockchain. again this transaction gets added into one block and most importantly, the current state database will get updated with this latest value and old value will be updated and the version also get changed to 2.

Comment: Ok so if, for example, I make a GET after your last transaction, like
`get-car1 - {"name": Audi, "owner": PQR}`, I will have this:

- Read Set: Key-car1, `version-2`, value-{"name":"Audi", "owner":"PQR"}
- Write Set: NA

We will have a new block in the ledger but the world state will not change, right?

Comment: For query tx, it doesn't create Read/Write set, it just fetches record form couch DB through peer, who always have latest record.